# JAVA Spring Form Input Requirement

Tags: java, spring

So I am using this format for input and was wondering if there was a way to add a required pattern like minimum/maximum characters, at least 1 letter, at least 1 number.

```
<tr>
  <td><form:label path = "firstName">Enter First Name: </form:label></td>
  <td><form:input path = "firstName" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must validate it on client-side (using javascript) and on server-side (using [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression))

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "input validation". There is a "Getting Started" guide over at [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) which will help to get you started.

You can also do client-side validation using either Javascript or if you are targetting newer browsers [HTML5](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/). However server-side validation should always be done!